# why I'm not able to run Rstudio from locally compiled R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have compiled latest version of R locally and it works well. 
When I would like to run Rstudio, I face with following error.
Can someone help me to figure out the problem?

> R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?

Comment: When you compiled it,  did you use the --enable-R-shlib option?

Comment: No ,i didn't. How can I change it?